# Header won't go to the edge on the top

Tags: html, css

I want to move the header up to the topmost. But it won't go, here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DCtH7/4/

As you see in the fiddle, there is a white space above the header. I tried `padding: 0` but it won't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `position: absolute` to the header

```
header {
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/DCtH7/6/

As an alternative way change margin to padding here:

```
header #header-content {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

This will also fix the problem without use any absolute position

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/DCtH7/7/

Comment: I would suggest not using `position: absolute;` as it will move the `header` out of flow. Hence in your first fiddle you can see the `parent-container` is being pushed underneath, overlapping the `header`

Comment: Indeed that's why I suggest the second solution too

Comment: thank you, i know this is very basic sorry for that still new to html